# This is undefined in callback function

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify, angular11

I'm tryin to upload my data from my angular app to s3 using aws amplify sdk.
The code is simple and works

```
await Storage.put(this.apkFileToUpload[0].name, this.apkFileToUpload[0], {
  progressCallback(progress) {
    console.log(`Uploaded: ${progress.loaded}/${progress.total}`);
  },
});
```

But i want to show the progress of the upload to the user. I added in my typescript

```
uploadProgress = 0;

await Storage.put(this.apkFileToUpload[0].name, this.apkFileToUpload[0], {
  progressCallback(progress) {
    console.log(`Uploaded: ${progress.loaded}/${progress.total}`);
    this.uploadProgress =  (progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total;
  },
});
```

and my html

```
          <div class="" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 180px; height: 180px">
            <div class="">
              <progressbar [value]="this.uploadProgress" type="warning" [striped]="true" style="height: 180px">{{ this.uploadProgress }}%</progressbar>
            </div>
          </div>
```

But i got this error

```
ERROR TypeError: this is undefined
    progressCallback apk-release.component.ts:125
    put AWSS3Provider.js:279
    emit events.js:152
    progressChanged AWSS3ProviderManagedUpload.js:349
    setupEventListener AWSS3ProviderManagedUpload.js:343
    emit events.js:152
    onUploadProgress axios-http-handler.js:71
    Angular 14
    dispatchXhrRequest xhr.js:150
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    xhrAdapter xhr.js:11
    dispatchRequest dispatchRequest.js:59
    Angular 22
    digest webCryptoSha256.js:35
    Angular 35
    RxJS 5
```

How could i do to get my data and update the value of the progress from my callback ?

Comment: Why are you using `this.uploadProgress`?

Comment: @kellys so i can get the value of the progress and display it in my front end. Otherwise, how could i get it ?

Answer (score 1):

The callback was not correct

```
await Storage.put(this.apkFileToUpload[0].name, this.apkFileToUpload[0], {
  resumable: true,
  completeCallback: (event) => {
    console.log(`Successfully uploaded ${event.key}`);
    this.test();
    console.log(event);
    //We call the back end to notify that a new apk is available
  },
  progressCallback: (progress) => {
    console.log(`Uploaded: ${progress.loaded}/${progress.total}`);
    this.uploadProgress =  (progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total;
  },
  errorCallback: (err) => {
    console.error('Unexpected error while uploading', err);
  }
});
```